# How to Secure SQL in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms

I have the following code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string addNewNote(string id, string txt)
    {
        Guid parentId = new Guid(id);
        DbProviderFactory dbf = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory();
        using (IDbConnection con = dbf.CreateConnection())
        {
            con.Open();
            using (IDbTransaction trn = con.BeginTransaction())
            {

                Guid noteId = Guid.Empty;
                SqlProcs.spNOTES_WebForms
                        (ref noteId,
                        parentId,
                        "Files",
                        "Client Note",
                        txt,
                        true
                        );
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

In other languages such as PHP, there exist functions such as `strip_tags` or `addslashes` or `mysqlrealescapestring` that would sanitize or otherwise clean client-based variables before inserting them into the database.

Do any such functions exist, or are any such functions required in C# ASP.NET.  I am already using a stored procedure, as you can see.

Comment: Have you looked into using [SQL paramters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)?

Comment: I don't know, but in this case I am using a stored procedure so I am not sure I can use SQL stuff.  I was thinking I would just be able to sanitize the data in C#, first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use parametrized queries .Net will handle the variable sanitation for you.

Comment: My stored procedure generated the following code `IDbDataParameter parID                = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@ID"               , gID                 );` (for example).  Are you saying this is safe to use as is?

Comment: May I ask, after having looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx, where does it say that this sanitizes incoming data?  Thanks.

Comment: Read here in the `Use Type-Safe SQL Parameters` section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(SQL.105).aspx `input is treated as a literal value instead of as executable code`

Comment: Alright, I guess I can trust to leave it as is, then.  Thanks!